# Disable Cancel button on fullscreen dialog

Tags: flutter

I'm pushing a screen with fullscreenDialog set to true.  There is a cancel icon added to the top left.  I want to replace this cancel icon with my own icon and functionality (delete).  How can I override that icon?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Which icon is there by default that you want to override?

Comment: Its an X.  I want to replace it with the delete icon (trash can) and capture when it is tapped.  I can add other icons to the app bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `leading` property of `AppBar` to override that X button. See below example:

```
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text("2nd page"),
  leading: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.delete), 
    onPressed: (){
    // handle delete here
   }),
)
```

Comment: That is how you add buttons the the AppBar.  I want to replace the cancel button that Flutter is adding by default.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot because I don't see any cancel button added by flutter on its own. There are other icons that flutter can add for you like back icon, hamburger icon.

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. I have never done iOS but to me it seems like this is Android back button, so you need to return `WillPopScope` and override `onWillPop` to handle this behavior.

Comment: That allows me to detect when they tap the icon.  But it doesn't allow me to change the icon to a delete icon.

Comment: Updated the answer and checked it myself too.

Answer (score 1):

```
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text("2nd page"),
  leading: Container()
)
```

If you want the button hidden.

Answer (score -1):

```
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.profile),
      leading: null,
      leadingWidth: 0,
     )
```